# SSRS Expression Count values in one column where values in first column equal each other

Tags: count, expression, unique

I have searched for an answer with no luck. I've tried Lookup and CountDistinct.
In the table below I need to count the number of distinct Records that have both an A and B in box 1. I'd like to do this in an expression as I want to use the same dataset to pull up other combinations of results. Please note I have multiple datasets in this report. There's a reason for this insanity. I greatly appreciate any help.

`Record Box File
   01    1    A
   01    1    B
   01    2    B
   01    2    B
   02    1    A
   02    1    B
   02    2    B
   03    1    B
   03    1    B`

Answer (score 0):

Try to adjust your table a little bit to have the **File** column in the detailed row, then add a parent group by **Box**. In your detailed row, use the count expression on **File**.

Comment: I don't believe so, you can do the grouping in SSRS (table grouping) or do your grouping and aggregate in your dataset query.